# 'abort: no repository found' when trying to install Vim through Mercurial

Tags: vim, ubuntu-12.04, mercurial

I'm new to Linux (which I'm setting up to start teaching myself web development). I am installing Vim, and in order to do so installed Mercurial.

`hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg vim` seemed to work fine, but when I try to update to the newest version using `hg pull` and `hg update` I get this after `hg pull`:

```
abort: no repository found in '/home/steven' (.hg not found)!
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Some details on my setup: Dual boot computer with Windows on one SSD harddrive and Linux on a separate optical drive. Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing this issue ***abort: no repository found in '/home/username/path/to/project' (.hg not found)!***

then probably .hg is missing in that repository. Run this command in terminal

```
hg init
```

once it is done use rest of the command normally to push your code in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

*(I've posted the same answer on the same question over at SO)*

1. You don't need Linux to learn Web dev: Windows and Mac OS X are equally fine.
2. You don't need to install Vim from the sources (and thus Mercurial) because it's already on your machine:

   1. summon the "Dash"
   2. type `ter`
   3. open *Terminal*
   4. type `vim` at the prompt and press `<Enter>`

   This CLI version of Vim is probably a "tiny" build which is going to lack a few useful features.

   A much proper Vim with a GUI frontend and more features is available through Ubuntu's package management system. To install it, you only need to launch *Ubuntu Software Center*, search for "gvim" and install it. This should be enough.

   If you need more control on the installation, you can install a second package manager called *Synaptic* which is less sexy than *Software Center* but a lot more detailed. In *Synaptic*, search for "vim-gnome" and/or "vim-nox".
3. To answer your question: the cloning created a "vim" directory in your "home": `/home/steven/vim` or `~/vim` (`~` being a shortcut for `/home/steven`). This "vim" directory is a self contained Mercurial repository and that's where you are supposed to issue any further Mercurial-related commands:

   ```
   $ hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg vim
   $ cd vim <-- "change directory"
   $ hg something
   ```

   But *you don't have to do that:* the sources you get after the cloning are up to date and ready to be built.

Good luck and welcome on Linux (and SO).

Comment: Thanks for the very through answer.  Yeah, I had a windows development environment set up for Ruby on Rails (which is the framework I'll be learning) on my last computer, but wanted to go all the way and "do it right" so to speak.  I know it's perfectly fine to use windows, but I'd like the added benefits that Linux provides, and plus it gives me an excuse to work in this OS.

Comment: I can understand that: I've switched from Mac OS X to Linux about two years ago because I almost exclusively used UNIX/CLI tools. I don't miss anything.